# Android: compile SDL selected processor does not support Thumb mode `swp r3,r3,[r0]'

Tags: android, arm, sdl

I'm trying to compile SDL2 library using the android NDK (rev8) , I'm targeting ARM , but when launching `ndk-build` I got the following error message

```
Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_spinlock.c
/tmp/ccMkkYeU.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccMkkYeU.s:33: Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode `swp r3,r3,[r0]'
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2/src/atomic/SDL_spinlock.o] Error 1
```

I'm on Ubuntu , I've tried with different version of Gcc (4.4.3 , 4.6 and 4.7) , also tried with clang3.1 , but always the same error message and Google is not of a great help on this problem

Does someone where the problem come from or know a link where I can find precise instruction on how to build the SDL library ?

Comment: `SWP` is deprecated/removed on ARMv7. It should (according to my understanding) be replaced by `LDREX`/`STREX`. Or maybe you could just throw out SDL's spinlock implementation and use something else, like pthread's spinlocks.

Comment: @Michael, actually in the SDL_spinlock.c there's also the ldrex version, but using it doesn't seems to be of any help, that's very weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set arm mode in your Android.mk

```
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it does not change anything, note that without using the SDL I can correctly compile my C code (using directly GL) and generate a working APK

Comment: actually it works, i was not putting it in the correct Android.mk, and as a more SDL specific answer, their own android.mk is actually containing something to resolve it (they rename the file in  .c.arm ), my mistake was that i was copying only the SDL src folder while you need to symlink the complete folder (that contains their android.mk) , thanks again